# get time slots with rules

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have this database (mariaDB) structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `ID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `evt_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `service` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



INSERT INTO `events` (`ID`, `evt_id`, `service`, `start`, `end`) VALUES
(464, '5423', 2, '2021-06-21 18:00:00', '2021-06-21 19:00:00'),
(465, '5424', 3, '2021-06-22 18:00:00', '2021-06-22 19:00:00'),
(474, '5436', 0, '2021-06-19 09:00:00', '2021-06-19 10:00:00'),
(475, '5437', 0, '2021-06-23 18:00:00', '2021-06-23 21:00:00'),
(476, '5438', 0, '2021-06-24 16:00:00', '2021-06-24 17:00:00'),
(477, '5439', 2, '2021-06-21 16:00:00', '2021-06-21 17:00:00'),
(478, '5441', 2, '2021-06-21 17:00:00', '2021-06-21 18:00:00'),
(479, '5442', 1, '2021-06-30 17:00:00', '2021-06-30 18:00:00'),
(480, '5443', 1, '2021-06-28 17:00:00', '2021-06-28 18:00:00'),
(484, '5447', 1, '2021-06-23 17:00:00', '2021-06-23 18:00:00'),
(486, '5449', 2, '2021-06-22 17:00:00', '2021-06-22 18:00:00'),
(491, '5450', 2, '2021-06-23 16:00:00', '2021-06-23 17:00:00'),
(494, '5455', 1, '2021-06-25 15:00:00', '2021-06-25 16:00:00'),
(495, '5456', 2, '2021-06-25 16:00:00', '2021-06-25 17:00:00'),
(496, '5457', 1, '2021-06-25 17:00:00', '2021-06-25 18:00:00'),
(497, '5458', 3, '2021-06-25 18:00:00', '2021-06-25 19:00:00'),
(498, '5459', 2, '2021-06-25 14:00:00', '2021-06-25 15:00:00');
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=e747c069fd2813d1f936d0a77a41a6c7

In my table events are all booked events available.
Now I would like to know, which time slots are free from current date until current date + 30 days AND only between 14:00 and 18:00 o'clock

For this I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL day.seq DAY), INTERVAL hour.seq HOUR) as freetime
FROM 
seq_0_to_30 AS day, 
seq_14_to_18 AS hour
HAVING freetime NOT IN ( SELECT `start` FROM `events`)
```

This works fine !
But now I have to expand my query.
I would like to know the free time slots (like above) but If a event with service ID 1 was booked on this day, all time slots after should not be available.

How I have to modify my query to realize this?

Example:

There is a booked event on 2021-06-28 17:00:00 with service ID 1.
with my query above, the following free time slots will shown:

```
2021-06-28 14:00:00
2021-06-28 15:00:00
2021-06-28 16:00:00
2021-06-28 18:00:00
```

But the one with 18:00:00 should not be available because the event before (17:00:00) has service ID 1.

Notice: We can also use a mysql query instead of a mariaDB query.

Comment: Add according `AND NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: can you show an example please ? :/ In which part I have to put this line?

Comment: `In my table events are all booked events available.` Eh?

Comment: In my table , named 'events' are all booked events stored

Comment: seq_0_to_30 - that's a nifty feature !

Answer (score 1):

You can use EXISTS AND BETWEEN

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `events` (
>   `ID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>   `evt_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
>   `service` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `start` datetime NOT NULL,
>   `end` datetime NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
>
>
> INSERT INTO `events` (`ID`, `evt_id`, `service`, `start`, `end`) VALUES
> (464, '5423', 2, '2021-06-21 18:00:00', '2021-06-21 19:00:00'),
> (465, '5424', 3, '2021-06-22 18:00:00', '2021-06-22 19:00:00'),
> (474, '5436', 0, '2021-06-19 09:00:00', '2021-06-19 10:00:00'),
> (475, '5437', 0, '2021-06-23 18:00:00', '2021-06-23 21:00:00'),
> (476, '5438', 0, '2021-06-24 16:00:00', '2021-06-24 17:00:00'),
> (477, '5439', 2, '2021-06-21 16:00:00', '2021-06-21 17:00:00'),
> (478, '5441', 2, '2021-06-21 17:00:00', '2021-06-21 18:00:00'),
> (479, '5442', 1, '2021-06-30 17:00:00', '2021-06-30 18:00:00'),
> (480, '5443', 1, '2021-06-28 17:00:00', '2021-06-28 18:00:00'),
> (484, '5447', 1, '2021-06-23 17:00:00', '2021-06-23 18:00:00'),
> (486, '5449', 2, '2021-06-22 17:00:00', '2021-06-22 18:00:00'),
> (491, '5450', 2, '2021-06-23 16:00:00', '2021-06-23 17:00:00'),
> (494, '5455', 1, '2021-06-25 15:00:00', '2021-06-25 16:00:00'),
> (495, '5456', 2, '2021-06-25 16:00:00', '2021-06-25 17:00:00'),
> (496, '5457', 1, '2021-06-25 17:00:00', '2021-06-25 18:00:00'),
> (497, '5458', 3, '2021-06-25 18:00:00', '2021-06-25 19:00:00'),
> (498, '5459', 2, '2021-06-25 14:00:00', '2021-06-25 15:00:00');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL day.seq DAY), INTERVAL hour.seq HOUR) as freetime
> FROM 
> seq_0_to_30 AS day, 
> seq_14_to_18 AS hour
> HAVING NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM `events` WHERE  freetime >=  `start` AND  freetime < `end`
> OR IF(`service` = 1,IF(DAY(freetime) = DAY(`start`),1,0),0))
> ```
>
> ```
> | freetime            |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2021-06-24 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-06-24 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-06-24 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-06-24 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-06-26 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-06-26 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-06-26 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-06-26 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-06-26 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-06-27 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-06-27 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-06-27 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-06-27 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-06-27 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-06-29 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-06-29 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-06-29 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-06-29 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-06-29 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-01 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-01 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-01 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-01 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-01 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-02 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-02 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-02 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-02 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-02 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-03 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-03 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-03 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-03 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-03 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-04 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-04 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-04 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-04 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-04 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-05 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-05 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-05 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-05 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-05 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-06 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-06 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-06 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-06 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-06 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-07 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-07 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-07 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-07 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-07 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-08 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-08 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-08 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-08 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-08 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-09 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-09 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-09 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-09 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-09 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-10 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-10 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-10 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-10 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-10 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-11 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-11 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-11 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-11 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-11 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-12 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-12 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-12 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-12 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-12 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-13 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-13 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-13 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-13 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-13 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-14 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-14 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-14 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-14 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-14 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-15 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-15 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-15 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-15 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-15 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-16 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-16 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-16 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-16 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-16 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-17 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-17 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-17 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-17 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-17 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-18 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-18 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-18 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-18 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-18 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-19 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-19 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-19 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-19 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-19 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-20 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-20 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-20 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-20 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-20 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-21 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-21 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-21 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-21 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-21 18:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-22 14:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-22 15:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-22 16:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-22 17:00:00 |
> | 2021-07-22 18:00:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=474441b70b62b41b72fe6a37894d18d3)*

Comment: thank you very much, but there is a mistake: in the table events exist already an event with start  2021-06-22 18:00:00. your freedom result shows this event as free. Thats not right

Comment: no in your table is no row with **serviceid 1** and that time slot at least  i can't see it, so please tell me Which ID you mean

Comment: (465, '5424', 3, '2021-06-22 18:00:00', '2021-06-22 19:00:00'),

Comment: I added the Query without excluding all other serviceid

Comment: Okay maybe I explained it wrong: all booked events (service ID no matter) should not be list as free time AND also no time slots after a booked event with service ID 1

Comment: i add another query the last one which ignores the serviceid takes all events into accountaccount

Comment: okay and where is now the logic which checks additional, if there is a event with service id = 1 and will not show the free time slots after this event as available ?

Comment: Good, i exclued all days that have in this case serviceid 1 ``service` = 1`determines which ids should be checked and can be expolanded with OR, the rest should be clear

Comment: hmmm something is wrong. why 2021-06-24 17:00:00 is missing ?

Comment: its at the sixt row

Comment: no at the sixt row (freetime) is 2021-06-24 18:00:00. But 2021-06-24 17:00:00 is also a freetime and is missing

Comment: I changed the date select from BETWEEN to a better suited Version